# flutter-web - Avoid initialRoute from initiating when the app launched with a different route via the browser's address bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

New to Flutter.

I'm making an app that has a splash screen that initially shows up when the user opens the app. After 3 seconds, the app will show the login or the dashboard screen, depending on the authentication state.

Here's my code.

**main.dart**

```
void main() { 
  runApp(myApp);
}

MaterialApp myApp = MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: "/",
  routes: {
    "/": (context) => SplashScreen(),
    "/signin": (context) => SignInScreen(),
    "/notes": (context) => NotesScreen(),
  },
);
```

**splash_screen.dart**

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _goToNextScreen();
  }

  void _goToNextScreen() {
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds:3),
      () async {
        AuthState authState = await Auth.getAuthState();
        String route = authState == AuthState.SIGNED_IN ? "/notes" : "/signin";
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, route);
      }
    );
  } 

  // build() override goes here...
}
```

I've been debugging the app with a web-server. When the app launches with the url localhost:8000/, everything seems fine. However, if the app started with the url localhost:8000/notes, the splash screen, I think, still gets initiated. What happens is the app will show the notes screen, then after 3 seconds, the app will open another notes screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: If you're not using Navigator 2.0, then the accepted answer should fix the issue mentioned above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because first render always started at root '/', it's preferable to use your own path for splash screen, like

`initialRoute: '/splash'`.

To hide this path in the address bar, replace *routes* map with route generator:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {

        // print current route for clarity.
        print('>>> ${settings.name} <<<');

        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/splash':
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SplashScreen(),
              // settings omitted to hide route name
            );
          case '/signin':
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SignInScreen(),
              settings: settings,
            );
          case '/notes':
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => NotesScreen(),
              settings: settings,
            );
          case '/':
            // don't generate route on start-up
            return null;
          default:
            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => FallbackScreen(),
            );
        }
      },
      initialRoute: '/splash',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but then will for my website `website.com/` it will return null and i will always have to use `website.com/splash` ?

Comment: It did skip the initialRoute '/' using '/splash', and I was able to navigate specific url manually in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

See since the main logic is we cannot have await in the init state so the page will build irrespective of the any logic you provide. I have a solution to this, there may be some advance or other good solutions too, so this is what I would use.

I would use a concept of future builder. What it will do is wait for my server and then build the whole app.

So process is

1. In your main.dart
   use

   ```
    Future<void> main() async {
      try {
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

    //await for my server code and according to the variable I get I will take action
    //I would have a global parameter lets say int InternetOff
        await checkServer();
        runApp(MyApp());
      } catch (error) {
        print(error);
        print('Locator setup has failed');
    //I can handle the error here
      }
    }
   ```

Now MyApp stateless Widget that will help us choose our path

```
class MyApp extends Stateless Widget{
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//Using this FutureBuilder 
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        // AsyncSnapshot<Your object type>

// Now if InternetOff is equal to one I would make it go to home 
if(InternetOff==1) return MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData.light(),
              home: CheckInternet(),
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            );
//else go to Home similarly with these if and else you can add more conditions
else {
             
              return MaterialApp(
                theme: ThemeData.dark(),
                home: UserHome(),
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              );
            }
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, flutter-web like any other Single Page Application supports hash based routing. As a result if you want to access

> localhost:8000/notes

you have to access it as

> localhost:8000/#/notes

**Cleaner way to handle auth state**

Call getAuthState function before runApp() to make sure that the auth state is set before app is initialized. And pass authState to SplashScreen widget as parameter.

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  AuthState authState = await Auth.getAuthState();
  runApp(MaterialApp myApp = MaterialApp(
    initialRoute: "/",
    routes: {
      "/": (context) => SplashScreen(authState: authState),
      "/signin": (context) => SignInScreen(),
      "/notes": (context) => NotesScreen(),
    },
  ));
}
```

**splash_screen.dart**

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final AuthState authState;
  SplashScreen({Key key, this.authState}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _goToNextScreen();
  }

  void _goToNextScreen() {
    Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds:3),
      () async {
        String route = widget.authState == AuthState.SIGNED_IN ? "/notes" : "/signin";
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, route);
      }
    );
  } 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And if you want even more cleaner way to handle auth state, you have to use state management solution like Provider.

Comment: Does it work both with mobile and web version?

Comment: Yes it would work both will mobile and web. Though for web if you want to a better routing solution, you can look into Navigator 2.0